# Cartesian product works well in JavaScript but not in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

If have this short utility-code for generating the Cartesian Product of any number of arrays:

```
const f = (a, b) => [].concat(...a.map(d => b.map(e => [].concat(d, e))));
const cartesian = (a, b, ...c) => (b ? cartesian(f(a, b), ...c) : a);
```

For example:

```
console.log(cartesian([1, 2, 3], [4, 5]));
```

Gives:

```
[ [ 1, 4 ], [ 1, 5 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 3, 5 ] ]
```

But when I try to port this from JavaScript to TypeScript, I get the following error:

```
error TS2557: Expected at least 2 arguments, but got 1 or more.

const cartesian = (a, b, ...c) => (b ? cartesian(f(a, b), ...c) : a);
                                                          ~~~~
const cartesian = (a, b, ...c) => (b ? cartesian(f(a, b), ...c) : a);
                      ~
An argument for 'b' was not provided.
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46228488/7400903) stating that spread operator works only when all parameters are marked as optional.

But I'm not sure how to apply that in my code (`...c?` doesn't seem to work), and to be honest - I'm not even sure that's the correct solution.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You have to type `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: The primary problem here is that you cannot make a rest parameter optional. Rest parameters are already implied to be optional. Arguments supplied after the required/optional parameters (even none) are all collated and represented by that rest parameter. So if you execute `cartesian(var1, var2)` then `c` in your function will be equal to an empty array, `[]`. By putting the optional operator after your rest parameter, you're setting it's type to `(Inferred/stated type) | undefined` and you cannot spread a non-array type: `...undefined` will never work. `...[undefined]` does though.

Comment: Hi @NoamManos. As far as I can tell, my edit was a good one here. If you wish to discuss it, please ping me here, or open a chatroom. I have a fair degree of confidence that edits to improve technical writing are supported by the community and mods. I am always happy to hear other points of view.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - the question mark should be applied on the second argument:

```
const cartesian = (a, b?, ...c) => (b ? cartesian(f(a, b), ...c) : a);
```