# Typescript TS2345 Arguments Spread Compile Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, spread-syntax

I'm not sure where to check, but I have a nodejs/TS folder that builds correctly on my laptop, but fails on my desktop.  The code is:

```
        const result: GetResourceXHR = {
            ...p,
            done( s: ajaxGetResourceSuccessCallbackSpread ) {
                p.done(function (...args) {
                    // s.call(p, ...args, resourceResult);
                    s.call(p, args[ 0 ], args[ 1 ], args[ 2 ], resourceResult);
                });
                return result;
            }
        };
```

And my callback interface is:

```
// Because this uses spread operator, all params have to be optional... https://stackoverflow.com/a/46228488/166231
interface ajaxGetResourceSuccessCallbackSpread {
    ( data?: any, textStatus?: string, jqXHR?: JQuery.jqXHR, resource?: KatAppResourceResult ): void;
}
```

On my laptop, I can use:
`s.call(p, ...args, resourceResult);`

But on my desktop, I get the error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'KatAppResourceResult' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

That is why above I have changed it to:
`s.call(p, args[ 0 ], args[ 1 ], args[ 2 ], resourceResult);`

Both machines have:
Visual Studio Code: 1.53.2
Typescript: 4.1.5

I would like to continue to just use the spread syntax, but more importantly, I want to figure out why it is building differently.  As additional note, I copied entire folder from my laptop and opened it on my desktop and received the same error.  I don't know if this helps, but I wasn't sure if some of the underlying nodejs libraries were different or what.

Comment: Are versions of node and npm the same?

Comment: Does that affect the TS compilation?  Node.js is 12.18.3 on both.  How do I check npm?